# Can a component handle multiple directories in Weblate?

Tags: git, gitlab, weblate

Is there a possible way to translate multiple files (.properties) within multiple directories using only one component in Weblate ? I know that i can use a single component for a single directory in Git but i have many directories in my case.

I have my branch with several directories, each of it contains several translation files .

for example

[image]

Specific goal : Is it possible to translate a key in German but only for a specific directory?

I have achieved to translate files but only if they are all together within a same path.

Thanks in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use language wildcard at any place in the path, but the paths within one component can differ only in the language name.

For example you can use something like `languagetool-language-modules/*/src/main/resources/org/languagetool/MessagesBundle_*.properties`